# Fill empty merged cells in range with top-left cell data that merged range

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
+--------+-----+-----+
|   A    |  D  |  F  |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

From values merged ranges array:

`[[A,  ,  ], [D,  ], [F,  ]]`

to this:
`[[A, A, A], [D, D], [F, F]]`

But looks like this code not work for me. Where is problem or is there better solution ?

```
let SpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
let Sheet = SpreadSheet.getSheets()[0];  
let CategoryRange = Sheet.getRange(1,1,1,Sheet.getLastColumn());
let CategoryMergedRanges = CategoryRange.getMergedRanges();
let CategoryData = CategoryRange.getValues();

  
for (let i = 0; i < CategoryMergedRanges.length; i++) {
    let CategoryName = "";
    for (let j = CategoryMergedRanges[i].getColumn(); j < CategoryMergedRanges[i].getColumn() + CategoryMergedRanges[i].getNumColumns(); j++) {
      if (CategoryData[0][j - 1].toString() != "") {
        CategoryName = CategoryData[0][i - 1];
      } 
    }    
    for (let j = CategoryMergedRanges[i].getColumn(); j < CategoryMergedRanges[i].getColumn() + CategoryMergedRanges[i].getNumColumns(); j++) {
        CategoryData[0][i - 1] = CategoryName;
    }
  }
Logger.log(CategoryData);
```

Comment: Do yourself a favour and don't merge cells as it destroys the main structural integrity of a spreadsheet. By working around it, you're kind of asking for bigger problems in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Explanation:

- According to your explanation: `A`, `D` and `F` are merged into `3`,`2` and `2`
  number of cells respectively.

Meaning that the merged ranges would be:

`[[A, , ], [D, ], [F, ]]`

**Assuming:**

- merged `A1:C1` with value `A` in cell `A1`
- merged `D1:E1` with value `D` in cell `D1`
- merged `F1:G1` with value `F` in cell `F1`

In order to fill in the empty cells using the first value of each array you can use the [fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) method.

The following script will give you the result in the screenshot.

---

### Solution:

```
function myFunction() {
  
let SpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
let Sheet = SpreadSheet.getSheets()[0];  
let CategoryRange = Sheet.getRange(1,1,1,Sheet.getMaxColumns());
let CategoryMergedRanges = CategoryRange.getMergedRanges();
let CategoryData = CategoryRange.getValues();
  
fAr = [];

CategoryMergedRanges.forEach(cmr=>
   { 
       let tempA=cmr.getValues().flat();
       fAr.push(tempA.fill(tempA[0],1));
   }
);

let ffAr = [fAr.flat()];
Sheet.getRange(2,1,1,ffAr[0].length).setValues(ffAr);
}
```

**Note that:**

`fAr` returns `[[A, A, A], [D, D], [F, F]]` which should be the desired format that you want.

`ffAr` returns `[[A, A, A, D, D, F, F]]` which is what I use to set the values back to the sheet (Optional).

[image: example]